# Jest unit test for react-native-tab-view

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Has anyone written a unit test for react-native-tab-view? I need to mock the props onIndexChanged and TabBar's getLabelText. Here is the mock we have

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from "react-native";

export class TabView extends View {
    render = function () {
        return <View>
            {this.props.renderTabBar()}
            {Object.values(this.props.renderScene)
                .map((scene, i) => <View key={i}>{scene()}</View>)}
        </View>;
    };
};

export const TabBar = View;
export const SceneMap = map => map;



Here is the TabView we are using. Any help is really appreciated.
```

```js
 <TabView
          navigationState={this.state}
          renderScene={SceneMap({
            current: () => <TorViewCurrent
              torCurrentList={this.props.torCurrentList}
              torCurrentListLoading={this.props.isLoading || this.props.torCurrentListLoading}
              torCurrentListLoaded={this.torCurrentListLoaded}
              torCurrentListError={this.props.torCurrentListError}
              torStatusMap={this.props.torStatusMap}
              torReasonMap={this.props.torReasonMap}
              torTypeMap={this.props.torTypeMap}
              refreshTorCurrentList={this.onRefreshTorCurrentList.bind(this)} />,
            past: () => <TorViewPast
              torPastList={this.props.torPastList}
              torPastListLoading={this.props.isLoading || this.props.torPastListLoading}
              torPastListLoaded={this.torPastListLoaded}
              torPastListError={this.props.torPastListError}
              torStatusMap={this.props.torStatusMap}
              torReasonMap={this.props.torReasonMap}
              torTypeMap={this.props.torTypeMap}
              refreshTorPastList={this.onRefreshTorPastList.bind(this)} />,
          })}
          onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
          initialLayout={styles.tabSize}
          renderTabBar={props =>
            <TabBar
              {...props}
              getLabelText={({ route }) => route.title}
              activeColor={WalmartColorPalette.Primary.Black}
              inactiveColor={WalmartColorPalette.Primary.IconGray}
              indicatorStyle={styles.tabIndicator}
              style={styles.tabs}
              labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
            />
          }
        />
```